# Error concatenating two files with ffmpeg ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ffmpeg

The following command works fine in OS X:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i videos_playlist.txt -c copy final.mkv
```

But when I try to run it on ubuntu i get the following:

```
Unknown input format: 'concat'
```

Any idea what I'm missing or a possible work around?

OS X build:

```
ffmpeg version 1.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Aug  8 2013 11:49:17 with Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.24) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
```

Ubuntu build:

```
ffmpeg version 0.10.8-7:0.10.8-1~precise1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on Sep  5 2013 14:56:20 with gcc 4.6.3
```

Answer (score 3):

Your ffmpeg build is simply too old. Download a recent [Linux build of ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds), or follow a step-by-step [guide to compile ffmpeg](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide).

Answer (score 2):

The error "Unknown input format: 'concat'" confirms that you don't have "`concat`" format enabled in your ffmpeg compilation.

Check formats by using the command

> ffmpeg -formats

Recompile your ffmpeg http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide